# What is the difference between screenshot and screencap in adb shell?

Tags: android, adb, screenshot

I have a Galaxy S i9000 with CyanogenMod 10 on it which supports both of these commands in adb shell and both take screenshots. They look a little different however.

Using `adb shell screenshot`:
[image: screenshot]

And using `adb shell screencap`:
[image]

It seems that `adb shell screenshot` lacks one colour channel, whereas `screencap` shows all the channels. I tried the same experiment on a Galaxy S4 with 4.4.2 KitKat and only `screencap` worked, leading me to believe that `screencap` is a newer version of `screenshot`.

Comment: `adb shell screenshot` looks like it swapped the red and the blue channel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`screenshot` worked directly with the `framebuffer` which is no longer supported in the recent Android versions

`screencap` is the new version of the tool which works through the `SurfaceComposer` instead.

Comment: How are these tools different from `adb emu screenrecord screenshot [DESITNATION]` https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#screenshots?

Comment: `framebuffer` method is also used by screenrecord. I am not sure what do you mean by no longer supported in the recent Android versions.  `adb emu screenrecord screenshot customFileName.png` https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/dq5f7i/emulator_2927_canary/f60xtyr/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3